# Reading and displaying images from a zip file in react using jszip

Tags: reactjs, image, blob, jszip

I have a zip file containing some images, mp4s and a text file. The text file i am reading like so:

```
      jszip
      .loadAsync(arrayBuffer)
      .then(({ files }) => {
        const txtFiles = Object.entries(files).filter(([fileName]) =>
          fileName.endsWith('.txt'),
        );

        if (!txtFiles.length) {
          throw new Error('No txt files found in archive');
        }

        return txtFiles
          .sort(([a], [b]) => a.length - b.length)[0][1]
          .async('string');
      })
```

and it works fine. But I need to get all the images/mp4s in the file as well, so I tried:

```
    jszip
      .loadAsync(arrayBuffer)
      .then(({ files }) => {
        const jpgs = [];
        const mediaFiles = Object.entries(files).filter(([fileName]) =>
          fileName.endsWith('.jpg'),
        );

        if (!mediaFiles.length) {
          throw new Error('No media files found in archive');
        }

        mediaFiles.forEach(i => {
          blob = new Blob([i], {
            type: 'image/jpeg',
          });

          img = new Image();
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          jpgs.push(img);
        });

        return jpgs;
      })
```

now when i try to render the jpgs array, i get a bunch of img elements like so:

```
<img alt="img" src="blob:http://localhost:3000/d64b16c7-aa9c-49a7-96cc-ed4eafc6a054">
```

but no images / broken image icons. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I wasn't using the blob correctly, the following code solved it for me, with thanks to [Loris Bettazza](https://github.com/Pustur):

```html
mediaFiles.forEach(([, image]) => {
  image.async('blob').then(blob => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.body.prepend(img);
  });
});
```